# SQL: Fetch rows based on even, odd values from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following tables:

```
course (course_id, title, dept_name, credits)
section (course_id, sec_id, semester, year, building, room_no, time_slot id)
instructor (id, name, dept_name, salary)
takes (id, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)
```

Need queries for:

1. Find the courses which are offered in both even and odd semester
2. Find the names of instructors who have taught at least one course in even semester 2012

This is from a past university exam question paper.

Comment: Show those _very lengthy non-optimal queries_.

Comment: Try to find a `MAGIC PEN` to complete your home work

Comment: @hjpotter92 Removed the last part to not sound so... 
After seeing TJDJD 's solution, I forgot mine. It involved distinct, two subqueries, union and %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think #2 is impossible because the instructor.id does not appear in any of the other tables.

For #1 you could try

```
SELECT *
FROM `course` `c`
INNER JOIN `section` `even` ON `c`.`course_id` = `even`.`course_id`
INNER JOIN `section` `odd` ON `c`.`course_id` = `odd`.`course_id`
WHERE `even`.`semester` % 2 = 0 
  AND `odd`.`semester`  % 2 = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Had to just add a distinct there to weed out the dups.